# UnicodeDecodeError for a Python script to extract URLs from a batch of JSON files

Tags: python, json, url, export

I'm trying to make a script for extracting URLs from a batch of JSON files but I'm getting this error I can't figure out how to resolve:
*UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 7837: character maps to*

It might be related to encoding but I'm not sure which one is needed and how to set it.

```
import json
import os
import re

# Directory containing JSON files
json_dir = r'C:/Users/manis/Downloads/cH/URLextract/Italy'

# Regular expression pattern for URLs
url_pattern = r'https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'

# Loop through all JSON files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(json_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(os.path.join(json_dir, filename), 'r') as f:
            # Load JSON data
            data = json.load(f)

            # Convert data to string
            data_str = json.dumps(data)

            # Extract URLs using regular expression pattern
            urls = re.findall(url_pattern, data_str)

            # Print URLs
            print(urls)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: The thing that saved these files, how did it do it? What encoding did it use to write the files? UTF-8 is the most common encoding for JSON. You may find that `with open(os.path.join(json_dir, filename), 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:` may work.

Comment: Why load JSON just to dump it to a string again? Since you prefer to use a regex to scan for urls instead of looking into the decoded collection, just read the file and use its text directly.

Comment: This is strange, I thought I responded before and marked an answer as accepted. Adding this did solve the problem: `with open(os.path.join(json_dir, filename), 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:`